# Enum to JSON object for jQGrid using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, enums, json.net

I'm having an issue trying to convert an `Enum` to JSON string for jQGrid. The format I was using before (doing a manually conversion) was this:

`{{0: '-', 1: 'Active', 2: 'Deactive', 3: 'Pending'}}`

```
    public static string GetStatuses(bool addDefault = false)
    {
        var statusesEnum = Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusEnum));
        string statuses = "{value: {0: '-', ";

        foreach (StatusEnum status in statusesEnum)
            statuses += String.Format("{0}: '{1}', ", (byte)status, Enum.GetName(typeof(StatusEnum), status));

        return statuses.Substring(0, statuses.Length - 2) + "}}";
    }
```

So I need to avoid this method because I think is not the best approach for this, I would like to serialize it using the JSON.NET library. So I wrote this:

```
public class StatusJSON
{
    public byte ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public StatusJSON() { }

    public StatusJSON(byte id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class JSONUtils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all the posible statuses of selected <paramref name="type"/> in JSON
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">Type of the status</param>
    /// <param name="addDefault">Check if add a default / NULL status</param>
    /// <returns>A string JSON with the statuses</returns>
    public static string GetStatuses(Type type, bool addDefault = false)
    {
        var statusesEnum = Enum.GetValues(type);
        List<StatusJSON> statuses = new List<StatusJSON>();

        if (addDefault)
            statuses.Add(new StatusJSON(0, "-"));

        foreach (var statusEnum in statusesEnum)
            statuses.Add(new StatusJSON((byte)statusEnum, Enum.GetName(type, statusEnum)));

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(statuses);
    }
}
```

You can use it as: `string statuses = JSONUtils.GetStatuses(typeof(StatusEnum), addDefault);`. The problem is than this return a string like:

`[{"ID":0,"Name":"-"},{"ID":1,"Name":"Active"},{"ID":2,"Name":"Deactive"},{"ID":3,"Name":"Pending"}]`

There's any method in the library to get a string like the one I need? Thanks

Comment: I don't think, since `{{0: '-', 1: 'Active', 2: 'Deactive', 3: 'Pending'}}` is not a valid json string. Maybe you should take a look at `StringEnumConverter` class

Answer (score 0):

What I did finally is re-use my old code. So now I have this:

```
public class Statutes
{
    public byte ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Statutes() { }

    public Statutes(byte id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all the posible statuses of selected <paramref name="type"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">Type of the status</param>
    /// <param name="addDefault">Check if add a default / NULL status</param>
    /// <returns>A list with the statuses</returns>
    public static List<Statutes> SelectAll(Type type, bool addDefault = false)
    {
        var statusesEnum = Enum.GetValues(type);
        List<Statutes> statuses = new List<Statutes>();

        if (addDefault)
            statuses.Add(new Statutes(0, "-"));

        foreach (var statusEnum in statusesEnum)
            statuses.Add(new Statutes((byte)statusEnum, Enum.GetName(type, statusEnum)));

        return statuses;
    }
}

public class JSONUtils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all the posible statuses of selected <paramref name="type"/> in JSON
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">Type of the status</param>
    /// <param name="addDefault">Check if add a default / NULL status</param>
    /// <returns>A string JSON for jQGrid with the statuses</returns>
    public static string GetStatusesJQGrid(Type type, bool addDefault = false)
    {
        var statuses = Statutes.SelectAll(type, addDefault);
        string result = "{value: {";

        foreach (Statutes status in statuses)
            result += String.Format("{0}: '{1}', ", status.ID, status.Name);

        return result.Substring(0, result.Length - 2) + "}}";
    }
}
```

You can use it as: `string statuses = JSONUtils.GetStatusesJQGrid(typeof(StatusEnum), true);`

Until I'll find a better approach using the JSON.NET I think this is a good piece of code to re-use for the people using jQGrid. This is valid for the select option:

`colModel: {name: 'status_id', label: 'Status', edittype: 'select', sortable: true, search: true, stype:'select', editoptions: " + statuses + @", searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq', 'ne']}}`